# Log from Sendmail and PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

If I leave my default sendmail options set in php.ini it works fine and sends an email. However if I change the sendmail path to:

```
sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i -x /var/log/mail.log"
```

mail() returns false.

If I run:

```
ls -l /var/mail/mail.log
```

I get:

```
-rwxrw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 0 Sep 17 14:49 /var/mail/mail.log
```

Which I believe is correct. All I want sendmail to do is log my emails but for some reason it really really doesn't want to play ball!

Just for clarity - this isn't the mail.log parameter which logs the PHP interactions with the script. The output when this is set is something like this:

```
[17-Sep-2016 15:38:20 Europe/London] mail() on [/home/server/www/dev1/htdocs/mail.php:15]: To: TO -- Headers: MIME-Version: 1.0  From: ME
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this instance was that I was using -x and not -X. Once I did the capital it worked fine!

Comment: Apparently this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP version 5.3.0 or newer then correct answer will be to use **mail.log** directive in configuration like said in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log).

Comment: I believe this is the PHP log not the mail log itself.

Comment: And I believe your *sendmail -t -i* command just deliver mail to local mailer daemon which already log all that related to mail delivery.
Try to look in /var/log/mail.log or something - maybe you already have all logs you need.